# Amazon Cognito Logout endpoint not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

While doing logout using AWS Cognito, I  am calling the Logout Endpoint. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html

Actually, the logout works only after I set the expiration date to -1 and then running the logout url. 
How to use the logout url properly?

Comment: When you evaluate logout I hope you are testing the validity of Refresh token?

Comment: Yes.. My nodejs webserver is behind a Load balancer. and the loadbalancer is interacting with Cognito to check the validity of the token. I think there is a session that is maintained between the load balancer and the browser. After further investigation, it looks like it is not an issue with the Cognito logout url. But I don't know how to destroy the session between loadbalancer and browser. If I set the expiration date of the session to -1 from the browser(can't do it using javascript since it is httpsOnly Cookie) and then run the Cognito logout url, it works.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57730555/6455343